# Save page to chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extenstion to save and load an webpage page. (Eg. You want to store a page before it gets changed, or you've modified the page yourself and want to save it).

What I've done right now is I am running code in the activetab to save the innerHTML of the page in localstorage with the key of the page URL.

```
'use strict';


let saveButton = document.getElementById('saveButton');

saveButton.onclick = function(element) {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tabs[0].id,
      {code: 'localStorage[window.location.href] = document.documentElement.innerHTML;'});
});
};


let loadButton = document.getElementById('loadButton');

loadButton.onclick = function(element) {
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tabs[0].id,
      {code: 'document.documentElement.innerHTML = localStorage[window.location.href];'});
});
};
```

This works okay, but I want it to be `chrome.storage.sync` so that it will be synced to the user's Google Account. 
*(and also this would not interfere with the page if it uses its url as a key)*

How can I accomplish this?

I've tried to use `chrome.storage.sync.set` inside of the tab, but that doesn't work (I'm assuming it has to somehow be done in the popup.js

Thanks.

Comment: I afraid `chrome.storage.sync` is inappropiate for your problem, as it has [severe restrictions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync)

Comment: @hindmost oh, that seems bad. so keeping it how it is is the best choice?

Comment: Yeah, though I'd say it's the only choice in your case)

Comment: @hindmost can I mark a comment as the answer on here?

Comment: Nope. But you can post your own answer. I won't mind.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an appropriate way to do this. `chrome.storage.sync` has major restrictions.